# how to convert string to decimal number while maintaining the decimal places in C#

Tags: c#

In C#, I have a custom string **"12.10"**, when I convert it to decimal it is converted as **12.1** but I need it to be **12.10** in decimal also, please help

Below is the code

```
 string Value = nudEngineeringYears.Value + "." + nudEngineeringMonths.Value;
 selStaff.EngineeringExperience = Convert.ToDecimal(Value);
```

Comment: Is 12.1 not equal to 12.10?

Comment: I don't understand, a decimal 12.10 is exactly the same as a decimal 12.1

Comment: Leading and trailing zeroes are only a concern for a text representation. When it's in binary form (ie `decimal`) this has no meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between a decimal with value 12.1 or value 12.10.

If you want to display the decimal with 2 decimal place, specify a format string in ToString:

```
myDouble.ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as math stays

```
12.1 == 12.10 == 12.100 == ...
```

etc. However, you can change number's *representation as a string* by formatting:

```
  12.1.ToString("F2"); // <- return 12.10 (note "2" in formatting string)
  12.1.ToString("F3"); // <- return 12.100 etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no decimal `12.10`, only `12.1`.

What you're talking about when you say `12.10` is a possible *representation* of that value.

There's no difference between 12.10 and 12.1 when talking about *numbers*, but there's a difference between the *string* `"12.10"` and the *string* `"12.1"`.

So don't confuse a number with its representation (which typically only matters in the front end).

If you want to *format* your value, you create a string representation of it. See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse the internal/binary representation of a floating point number with its representation when converted to a string.

Internally a float has always about seven places of precission,
a double about 15 places of precission, a decimal even more.

Only when you format such a binary value to a string you may specify the number of places **shown**. For formatting use `.ToString(format)` with the format you need. in your case `"F2"`